# Print labels using awk

Tags: unix, awk, sh, freebsd, ls

On my FreeBSD 10.1 I'm writing a little piece of code that basically calls  `ls` and automatically breaks the results down into something like this:

```
directory:
    2.4M .git
    528K src
    380K dist
    184K test
file:
    856K CONDUCT.md
    20K  README.md
........
```

You will only need to list out directories and regular files, and you don't have to list out `.` `..`, but you have to list out hidden files, and sort them from largest to smallest separately.

The challenge is to complete it **as a one-line command without using** `$(cmd)`, `&&`, `||`, `>`, `>>`, `<`, `;`, `&` and within 12 pipes (back quotes count as well).

Currently my progress is:

```
 ls -Alh | sort -d -h -r |
 awk 'BEGIN {print "Directories:"}
      NR>1 {if(substr($1,1,1)~"d")print"     "$5"     "$9}'
```

which prints out only until the last directory item. But since the entire command will output once every record, I can't find a way to print `files:` only once, and then print out the remaining output.

Comment: The `-h` option to sort is in GNU and FreeBSD `sort`, but not in Mac OS X `sort` (which is interesting because that is derived from BSD). The sizes of the directories intrigue me: on Mac OS X, the directories come back with small numbers (the length of the names in the directory plus some overhead per name), not the disk space used by the contents. Does the FreeBSD `ls` give the size of the contents of the directories? Or do you have to use `du -s -h` to get those? (I have a couple of UTF-8 Cyrillic files in the directory I play with, and `sort -d -r` screws those up unless `LC_ALL=C` is set.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may have to store the files in an array and print at the end:

```
ls -Alh|sed 1d|
  sort -h -k5r|
  awk 'BEGIN {print "Directories:"}
       /^d/{print "\t"$5"\t"$9}
       /^-/{f[n++]=sprintf("\t"$5"\t"$9)}
       END{print "Files:";
         for(i=0;i<n;++i)print f[i]}'
```

One additional problem you'll need to work out: files and dirs may have spaces in the name, and the simple `$9` will be insufficient for that case.